# Unable to mount 64GB Volume

Tags: volume-control

When I try and mount my 64GB volume I receive the following error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/sourav/3466-6438: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/sourav/3466-6438"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

What is the cause of this error and how can I solve it so I can mount my drive?